# phpfile include error in wordpress header

Tags: php, wordpress

i have this code in my home.php-

```
  <?php

   include('PHPLiveX.php');

 $ajax = new PHPLiveX();

    $ajax->Ajaxify(array("applyJob"));

    get_header();

    ?>
```

now i am moving this code to my header.php

```
include('PHPLiveX.php');

$ajax = new PHPLiveX();

$ajax->Ajaxify(array("applyJob"));
```

so that it will be available for all word-press file. but its giving me blank page(no error). i know that file is including because when i echo some content in the included file it shows in the page.the phplivex.php file contain a class which is used to ajaxify the theme. any guess wats causing the blank page?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

U Go in your theme and in your active theme open function.php And Add this Code.

**function.php**

```
function IncludeFileFun(){
    include('PHPLiveX.php');
}

add_action( 'init', 'IncludeFileFun' );
```

**Note**: PHPLiveX.php File is include in your active theme folde.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use complete real path of that file in-order to include it.

include('FULLPATHOFDIRECTORY/PHPLiveX.php');

FULLPATHOFDIRECTORY = has to be path to that directory which keep this file.

Comment: its including the file because when i echo the content in phplivex.php it show in all pages but after it nothing shows up.

Comment: Enable php error display so that you will get the error list what you php is countering. ini_set('display_errors', 1) & error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: Checkout application.log in runtime diretory you will get the trace or use Yii::log method to trace out where it causes issue. Seems like validation issue use insert method instead of save.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should use `include_once()` or `require_once()` when you call this file in header.php. Hope it helps.